# Console shows only old value (js, html)

Tags: javascript, html

so I've added slider that has range 0-4 and it shows value next to it but when I console log it shows only default value.

```js
const output = document.getElementById("output").value;
let smth = document.getElementById("smth1");
let tb = document.getElementById("Test-button");

tb.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(output)))
});
```

```html
</span><input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="4" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value"><output id="output">0</output><br>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why do you stringify the JSON, and then Parse it again?

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(output))` is a hacky way to create a deep copy of an object. This is pointless because (a) `output` is a primitive, not an object and (b) you don't do anything that would mutate the value later if it were an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the output is set on load, not on click.
Do like this instead.

```
let smth = document.getElementById("smth1");
let tb = document.getElementById("Test-button");

tb.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  const output = document.getElementById("output").value;
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(output)))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the old **value** (not a reference to the value) and storing it in a variable named `output`.

Later, when there is a click event you are reading the value of `output`.

If you want the new value of the the input's `value` property you need to read **that** inside the event listener.